# NLTK stopwords Python

Tags: python, nltk

I want to cleanup text files to be used as input to NLTK functions.  I have a custom list of stopwords that I want to remove as well as the NLTK conventional stopwords.  I also want to tokenize , convert to lower case, remove numerics and lemmatize  the text file. So I wrote a script to do this but I have encountered an error that I don’t understand or know how to correct.

T

```
filein=open("CustomStops.txt","r")        
stops=filein.read
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(cwd):
    for filename in filenames:
       with open(filename) as filein:
        fileinA = filein.read()
        #lower case
        fileinB=fileinA.lower()
        # tokenize the file
        fileinC = word_tokenize(fileinB)
         # alphanumeric
        fileinD=[word for word in fileinC if word.isalpha()]
        #remove stop words
        fileinE = [word for word in fileinD if not word in stops]
        #lemmatize
        fileinF=[wnl.lemmatize(word)for word in fileinE]
```

The program fails at the `#remove stops words` with an error message:

```
fileinE = [word for word in fileinD if not word in stops]
TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable
```

The custom and NLTK stopwords are in a text file in the form of a list. Following is an abbreviated version.
`['abell', 'abler', 'abramson', 'adam', 'adams', 'addison', 'adler', 'ahmed', 'ajello', ''from',  'wasn', 'hasn', 'aren', 'an', 'other']`

The fileinD (input to fileinE) has the  form;
`['test', 'test', 'test', 'abell', 'abler', 'abramson', ,adam', 'adams', 'addison', 'adler', 'ahmed',  'ajello', 'akins', 'al', 'alexander']`

I will appreciate help on understanding why the script is not working and any suggestions as to what needs to be modified.

Comment: You are missing parenthesis after `read` on the second line

Comment: What  a bonehead I am !!  Did not connect the error message with the read statement .....thanks mousetail !!